# Reducing the number of JAXB classes needed

Tags: xml, jaxb

I have an XML which is like this:

```
<player>  
<id>402</id>  
<name>Sean</name>  
<fitness>  
<speed>good</speed>  
<strength>super</strength>  
</fitness>  
</player>
```

The normal JAXB way for this would be to have two classes. One for Player; one for fitness. I think this is overkill.   Is there anyway I could just have a Player class with a Fitness attribute with smart use of annotations to cover this?

Also, say I am only unmarshalling.  I only have an interest fitness / speed. I have no interest in fitness / strength.  I'd really like to have just a speed attribute in my Player JAXB class. Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not with standard JAXB.  Proprietary extensions from the likes of MOXy might be able to do it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [JAXB 2 (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

As mentioned by [skaffman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21234/skaffman), MOXy has the `@XmlPath` extension that can be used for this use case:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder={"id", "name", "speed", "strength"})
public class Player {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    @XmlPath("fitness/speed/text()")
    private String speed;

    @XmlPath("fitness/strength/text()")
    private String strength;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: Thanks Blaise. Just checking through the release doc, I was looking to see what JDK versions your releases are compatable with?  Also, eclipselink is the reference implementation now for JPA.  Do you think we can see any of your ideas from MOXy making it into future JDKs?

Comment: @dublintech - EclipseLink MOXy requires a minimum of Java SE 5 (JDK 1.5).  As a member of the JAXB 2 expert group my intent is to have the most useful extensions included in future JAXB specifications.  This is also how we advance the JPA specification.  MOXy is now the default JAXB implementation in WebLogic 12c: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/eclipselink-moxy-is-jaxb-provider-in.html if you happen to be a WebLogic user.

Comment: One thing about JAXB is it doesn't like inner classes. It only allows static ones.  Does MOXy have any extra features here?

Comment: MOXy also requires that the inner classes be static.